# thread local storage of a function

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, queue

I am working on a program that requires a queue operation to be performed in multi threaded environment. 
I am not sure about the thread local storage for a function, not just a global variable 
i tried

```
__thread int head,tail;
__thread int q[MAX_NODES+2];

__thread void enqueue (int x) {
   q[tail] = x;
   tail++;
   color[x] = GRAY;
  }

__thread int dequeue () {
   int x = q[head];
   head++;
   color[x] = BLACK;
   return x;
   }
```

I got following error

```
fordp.c:71: error: function definition declared '__thread'

fordp.c:77: error: function definition declared '__thread'
```

I read somewhere that a function is already thread safe unless its using shared variables so I tried

```
__thread int head,tail;
__thread int q[MAX_NODES+2];

void enqueue (int x) {
   q[tail] = x;
   tail++;
   color[x] = GRAY;
   }

 int dequeue () {
   int x = q[head];
   head++;
   color[x] = BLACK;
   return x;
   }
```

It did compile with no error, but my execution result was wrong hinting queue didnt work well with multi-threaded platform.

Can someone please explain me what is going on here??

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`__thread` advises the compiler to create an instance of the variable for **every** thread.

I doubt that's what you want for the queue, it's head and tail the threads should **concurrently** operate on, as modifications done by one thread would **not** be visible by any other thread.

So do **not** use `__thread` here, but protect the concurrent access to the global variables, for example using one or more mutexes.

---

For your reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually in my program, queue in different threads will do different portion of job. So, as the job they will do is independent (I dont need mutex I guess), I wanted to create an instance of the variable for every thread so that variable (eg. head, tail) of one thread wont mix up with variable (head, tail) of another thread during multi-threading operation.

Comment: yes I have one queue instance for each thread and these queues are independent to each other. actually for 2 fixed threads I would have defined two separate queue as q1 and q2. The problem is when I have to write a program for n threads. Thats when instead of defining queue separately as q1,q2,q3.... in the program itself, I wanted to define queue once and take benifit of thread local storage to work it out in multiple threads. Do i make some sense!!!

Comment: @AbinashAdhikari: Yes, the requirement and the approach you describe absolutly make sense. However, you should add this information to your question, to avoid further misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're tackling the problem in the wrong way.

Your problem is that you want to associate a Queue object with a function call (e.g. `enqueue`).

In C these objects are usually referred to as contexts.

What you did is a variation of a global variable. Using per thread local storage is good for scratch space or actual per thread resources. and this is not the case.

The only option to have thread safety and correctness is to add the context to the function call.
I removed the reference to `color` to simplify things.

```
struct queue {
    unsigned head, tail;
    int q[MAX_NODES+2];
};

void enqueue (struct queue* q, int x) {
    q->q[q->tail++] = x;
}

int dequeue (struct queue* q) {
    int x = q->q[q->head++];
    return x;
}
```

**Note: you should perform checks on pointers and indexes.**

Comment: At least one sentence refering "thread local storage" would have suited your answer^H^H^H^H^H^Hproposal well.

Comment: No need to repeat your answer + comments. In this case just the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for reply. please let me ask one question. Suppose I perform different portion of job(requiring queue, enqueue and dequeue) with different thread. My worry is queue* q for above code. As the threads are performing different job, I want them to work on JUST their OWN copy of queue. My fear is enqueue and dequeue of one thread using queue of another thread. Does above code has that risk??

Comment: The above code is reentrant - will work on multiple thread where each works on a different queue struct/object. If you want thread safety (many threads on a single queue) you need to use some sort of lock (critical section or mutex). The mutex will be part of the queue structure. Some mutexes have spinlocks. This means that locking will first try to for X number of times to get the lock without a context switch (wait on mutex causes a context switch). So if the lock is unlocked or if the function exists very quickly then performance will be very good.

Comment: There are such things as lockless queues but they have limitations and in most cases not worth the effort.